# Почему .NET ищет библиотеки SqlCLR в папке windows?

Tags: .net, sql-server, dll, sqlclr

В приложении я работаю с типами DbGeometry соответственно использую библиотеку `SqlServerSpatial130.dll`. Что бы загрузить библиотеки я использую метод `LoadNativeAssembly` так же как в этом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880753/1382234.

Запускаю приложение и через Process Monitor вижу что приложение обращается к библиотекам лежащим в папке windows:

```
15:11:38,5893796    MyCoolApp.exe   10200   CreateFileMapping   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SqlServerSpatial110.dll FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS   SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection:
```

На компьютере установлены `SqlCLRType 2008-2016`. Т.е. в папках `system32 и SysWOW64` имею библиотеки:

```
SqlServeSpatial.dll
SqlServeSpatial110.dll
SqlServeSpatial130.dll
```

Собственно вопрос - почему так происходит? Почему приложение обращается к библиотекам не по пути который я задал в `LoadNativeAssembly`?

Comment: Возможно, библиотека была уже загружена другим кодом до того, как вы вызвали LoadLibrary. Что показывает Process Monitor до вызова LoadLibrary?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Вижу что обращение к библиотеке происходит только один раз при запуске приложения. Когда же происходит обращение к DBgeometry, обращение идет к библиотеке из папки windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> На компьютере установлены SqlCLRType 2008-2016

В том и проблема - у вас зоопарк SQL, и вы в них запутались.

Вы вручную загружаете неуправляемую DLL от версии SQL Server 2016, но при этом используете управляемую сборку SqlServer.Types от SQL Server 2012. Естественно, она игнорирует загруженную *SqlServerSpatial130* и грузит свою *SqlServerSpatial110* с пути по умолчанию. Приведите в соответствие управляемую и неуправляемую DLL, тогда все заработает как нужно. Сборку SqlServer.Types можно найти в каталоге

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\SDK\Assemblies
```

где XXX = 110 для SQL 2012 или 130 для SQL 2016